# Transpiling nodejs app with gulp-babel ignore doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I have created a task in gulp to transpile my nodejs app:

```
gulp.task('babel', function() {

    return gulp.src('./**/*.js')
        .pipe(babel({
            ignore: [
                './gulpfile.js',
                './node_modules/**/*.js',
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

the problem is that during the transpiling the node_modules folder and gulpfile are created in the dist folder. any idea why?

**gulpfile**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');

gulp.task('babel', function() {

    return gulp.src([
            './**/*.js',
            './server/config/manifest.' + (process.env['NODE_ENV'] || 'development') + '.json',
            '!./gulpfile.js',
            '!./node_modules/**/*.js'
        ])
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

gulp.task('start', ['babel'], function() {

    nodemon({
        script: './dist/server.js',
        ext: 'js jsx',
        tasks: ['babel']
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['start']);
```

Comment: You can exclude those files in `src` param, like with `['./**/*.js', '!./node_modules{,/**}', './gulpfile.js']`. In this case, those won't be processed by `babel` AND `dest` tasks.

Comment: @raina77ow I need to disallow my node modules (vendor folder) to go through Babel, but I still need these vendor files to be concatenated to my `app.js` file thru Gulp. In my `.babelrc` folder I've added `"ignore": ["node_modules", "vendor/*"]` without luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Babel's `ignore` just means they won't be transformed, but with that config gulp is still going to pipe them through. You probably want those patterns in an `ignore` option to `gulp.src`.

Edit: actually I forgot that the ability to exclude those patterns by passing an `ignore` option to `gulp.src` depends on how recent your `glob` version is (see my [bug report](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/194)). An alternative is the `!` negated patterns @raina77ow suggested.

Comment: JMM is there a way around to avoid that gulp.src create new file every time? I would like overwrite dist folder everytime

Comment: @mazzy I'm not sure what you mean by "create new file" -- doesn't it overwrite each file in `dist` each time?

Comment: no unfortunately every time nodemon restart the server a new dist folder is created inside the old dist folder creating nesting folders

Comment: @mazzy oh, ok, I think you're pulling `dist` in with your `gulp.src` glob each time. So you might want to put your files in a `src` directory next to `dist`.

Comment: @mazzy I'm on a phone so I can't make a great example right now, but I mean have `/somedir/dist` and `/somedir/src` and have `gulp.src('./src/**/*.js')`. Or you can probably work something else out, like excluding `dist` from your glob.